# Checking if 3 separate User inputs all match the values of a list of lists in Python

Tags: python, tuples

I am trying to create an extremely simple real estate database that would return a property based on a users criteria.

I have the following code:

```
import sys

def main():


    print ("What type of property are you looking for?")

    Type = input()

    print ("How big of a property are you looking for?")

    Size = input()

    print ("Are you looking to lease or purchase a property?")

    Listing_Type = input()


    a = ('Retail', 1500, 'Lease')
    b = ('Industrial', 1440, 'Sale')
    c = ('Office', 1000, 'Lease')

    Database = (a, b, c)

    for i in Database:
        if Type == Database[i[0]] and Size == Database[i[1]] and Listing_Type == Database[i[2]]:

            text = "There is a %c square foot %d space for %z" % (Database[i[1]], Database[i[0]], Database[i[2]])

        else:

            i += 1

        if matches == 0:
            print ("Sorry, there were no matching properties.")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When I run this I get the error TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str.

I am still trying to understand how this works. I need to check if the strings for property type and listing type match up, but also check if the size is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `Database[]` `in Database[i[0]]`, `in Database[i[1]]`, `in Database[i[2]]`, 
You are already iterating on `Database`, so `i` in the loop will be `a`, `b`, then `c`. To access the value of these tuples, `i[0]` is enough.

Comment: It looks like i'm getting closer, but my if statement doesn't seem to be matching my input with my lists. When I run the following if statement, I get a report that there weren't any matches even when I put in the correct criteria.

Answer (score 0):

i is in database
so first

```
i =('Retail', 1500, 'Lease')

i[0]='Retail'
```

so

```
database[i[0]]=database['Retail']
```

but database is a tuple not a dict

Answer (score 0):

change the line

```
for i in database:
```

to

```
for i in range(len(database)):
```